# How do you translate a dropdown in 2sxc?

Tags: c#, razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a 2sxc app that's on a multilingual DNN website. In my app, I use a lot of dropdown fields for content. How do I let users translate a dropdown selection for another language?

For example, if I have a content type for a person, and in that content type I have a field called "JobTitle" and it's a dropdown with three options:

1. Programmer
2. UI Developer
3. Designer

When I go to translate this field on the 2nd language, I only get these English options. Would I have to include the translations in the dropdown to begin with? Or rely on the translator to use the Free Text option in the field? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that you can just directly translate the Drop-down settings.

[image]